# Good practices on publishing node app

Tags: node.js

Not sure if this should be posted here but I'm really insterested in learning what is a good practice when I build a ZIP file that contains my node app ready to deployed.

Right now, I just run `zip -R app.zip root_folder` and use this zip to be deployed on production but it copies entire folders like `node_module/*` without any compression or minification. Is it normal when working with Node.JS? After I need to unzip and run `node supervisor.js`. I came from Scala/Java world and I used to generate a binary file to deployed.

I'm reading about GulpJS to generate a zip, run unit tests, jslint and other stuff but I don't think this will fit in my world.

Comment: _Continuous integration services_ work in the same way: create VM, install all dependencies, run build task, run tests, pack build and deploy it to the server. If you want to simplify the process or build sources and run tests before deployment, yes, you can use gulp, or even npm-scripts for that.

Comment: But why use Gulp instead npm-scripts? What is the advantage of Gulp?

Comment: In some cases gulp gives more opportunities. For example if you need to do the different tasks during the build process. But for simple tasks such as running tests or packing the app npm-scripts more preferable. Another problem with gulp is that, currently many gulp plugins are outdated unfortunately, and you need to use native libraries to do the task, and use npm-scripts of course.

Comment: Nice! And about a dist folder? Is it necessary or it's a common practice pack the project folder?

Comment: You must to deploy only files required to run your app on the server. You shouldn't pack the whole project folder, skip .git, tmp, tests, etc files. Because it's unsafe and increases the build size.

Comment: Ty for the help. I'll adopt that